# Better way to check that multiple variables doesn't have any duplicated value

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-statements

I have some of variables such as these strings:

```
string option1 ,option2, option3, option4;
```

with unknown value. It seems I can check that no two of them are equal in this way (no duplication):

```
if(option1 !=option2 && option1 != option3 &&...)
    //
```

but if I have many of variables then how can I do it not so ugly like above?

Comment: You can create extension method, and make it look better using fluent interface, but no. of conditions/checks remains the same.

Comment: If you have many variables but need to work with them all together, have you considered using an array instead?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You are right, but here I mean not so many that array of vars needs; i.e. here op1-op4 are answer of an Q on my Question table and it need c(4,2) checking which is a bit ugly.anyway I learn how to find duplications on array! :) Thanks for your notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably use LINQ with this, which of course requires putting them into a collection.

```
public static bool HasDuplicates<T>(params T[] arr)
{
    return arr.Distinct().Count() != arr.Length;
}
```

Of course, you'd call this as follows:

```
if(!HasDuplicates(option1 ,option2, option3, option4))
{
    // Code
}
```

There might be a better way to run that comparison, but this seems pretty straight-forward, and it's a good starting place, if nothing else.

Also, I wasn't completely sure whether you meant that you want to make sure `option1` isn't equal to any others, or that there aren't any duplicates. I went with the more complicated, latter case, but you could easily run a similar expression with `Contains` if I guessed wrong on that.

Comment: Ok. I want to not have any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can get another array which has distincts

```
int[] s = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4};
int[] q = s.Distinct().ToArray();
```